# Is it possible to define the "mid" range in scale_fill_gradient2()?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, legend

I am creating a heat map using `ggplot()`, and would like to utilize the 3 color scheme of `scale_fill_gradient2()`. I've found, however that the middle color is too broad and tends to display some of my data negatively (using "black" for example). Is it possible to define the range that is considered "mid," to make it more narrow? If not, is there a better way that I may do so?

Data Set:

```
structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), 
var2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", 
"q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x"), class = "factor"), 
corr = c(0.039063517, -0.012531832, 0.096287532, -0.156156609, 
-0.097044878, 0.144426494, 0.102142979, 0.061426893, 0.051079225, 
0.271860908, 0.156812951, 0.259456277, -0.121838722, -0.157440078, 
-0.037827967, -0.01929319, -0.108895665, -0.066815122, 0.254285337, 
0.12688199, -0.064394035, 0.00112601, 0.173774179, 0.01179886, 
0.105171013, 0.088559148, 0.033584364, -0.368075609, -0.272671354, 
-0.456557935, -0.441008229, -0.118498286, -0.309056047, 0.051624421, 
0.087594347, -0.0264506, 0.081249807, -0.194887615, -0.135397719, 
-0.078688964, -0.059544125, -0.065410158, 0.211446055, 0.027338504, 
-0.06185598, -0.007720807, 0.092997248, -0.177812491, 0.133226267, 
0.075247459, 0.04586679, -0.37972917, -0.254410003, -0.447919321, 
-0.426264017, -0.150347417, -0.270786314, 0.143483685, 0.230384468, 
-0.012297462, 0.096957204, -0.134348613, -0.056239035, -0.038059581, 
-0.040273741, -0.131126698, 0.222754865, 0.067883188, -0.154724805, 
-0.076366467, 0.152747678, -0.160657826, 0.104652439, 0.029599007, 
-0.02194356, -0.349623751, -0.228046427, -0.363148102, -0.326649794, 
-0.160199177, -0.253621489, 0.242711785, 0.242808683, 0.005937022, 
0.120849407, -0.131358491, 0.004558011, -0.056873299, 0.048745675, 
-0.147360978, 0.204314713, 0.033110005, -0.154644375, -0.095999454, 
0.202067265, -0.182694112, 0.071256125, 0.062783632, 0.078250678, 
-0.348208521, -0.237899511, -0.235431913, -0.249280276, -0.129802124, 
-0.084153729, 0.201859004, 0.292353092, -0.000270168, 0.130668616, 
-0.101519227, -0.024695776, -0.024373331, -0.05976031, -0.07861482, 
0.150316096, 0.100494694, -0.107507982, -0.06543542, 0.220813403, 
-0.159374132, 0.139677124, 0.005974473, 0.011484774, -0.423918147, 
-0.286712875, -0.286979217, -0.2730134, -0.095014441, -0.134216671, 
0.215551068, 0.432571228, 0.029945066, 0.178996421, -0.114005412, 
-0.098205883, 0.009661061, -0.07163473, 0.010722592, 0.175801779, 
0.170582102, -0.199407024, -0.15933157, 0.246575881, -0.084929336, 
0.160642274, 0.025941888, -0.058676465, -0.297996589, -0.180504241, 
-0.236672516, -0.228203539, -0.181349045, -0.091893083, 0.277145017, 
0.38119709, 0.019554381, 0.18725277, -0.019416086, 0.000417258, 
0.134560252, 0.059330986, -0.091994882, 0.11807573, 0.175219716, 
-0.169272253, -0.094240107, 0.180532375, 0.04322002)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "corr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -168L))
```

Code using `reshape2`, `ggplot2`, and `scales`:

```
sample.m <- melt(sample)
sample.m$var2 <- as.character(sample.m$var2)
sample.m$var2 <- factor(sample.m$var2, levels=unique(sample.m$var2),ordered=TRUE)
sample.m$var1 <- as.character(sample.m$var1)
sample.m$var1 <- factor(sample.m$var1, levels=unique(sample.m$var1),ordered=TRUE)
p <- ggplot(sample.m, aes(var2,var1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value), colour="transparent") +    scale_fill_gradient2(low="cyan", mid="black", high="red", midpoint=0, limits=c(-0.6,0.6))
base_size <- 9
p + theme_bw() + labs(x = "", y = "") + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8, angle = 310, hjust = 0, colour = "black"), axis.text.y = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8,colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try `scale_fill_gradientn` and the `values` argument. From `?scale_fill_gradientn`:

> if colours should not be evenly positioned along the gradient this vector gives the position (between 0 and 1) for each colour in the colours vector. See `rescale` for a convience function to map an arbitrary range to between 0 and 1.

Thus, resolution of the colour scale for values close to zero may be increased  by using suitable numbers in `values = rescale(...)`.

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("cyan", "black", "red"),
                       values = scales::rescale(c(-0.5, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.5)))
```

[image]

Comment: +1, didn't realize `colour` and `values` needn't be the same length, though in retrospect thinking about how this all works it makes sense.

Comment: Excellent! I adjusted to `(-0.5, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.5)` and it looks phenomenal.

Comment: @Henrik If colour are values are not the same length, then, how does colours get distributed across values? in your solution does the black colour goes from -0.05 to 0.05?

Comment: @chang02_23 Under the hood, [scale_fill_gradientn](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/scale-gradient.r) calls `scales::gradient_n_pal`, which in turn call `scales::colour_ramp`. Please check the code and the help text for these functions (and for `scales::rescale`) and play around with easy toy examples, and I think you will get a better feeling for how they work. Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

Try replacing your `scale_fill_gradient2` with:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(values=c(1, .6, .5, .4, 0), colours=c("red", "#770000", "black", "#007777", "cyan"))
```

You can adjust how narrow you want the black part to be by changing the `.6` and `.4` values (and also potentially the colors around "black"). This produces:

[image]

Compare to what you had:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of 21.03.2023, you can simply set the [midpoint](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html) to some value in `scale_fill_gradient2`

```
scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = 1000)
```

You can also select the midpoint color

```
scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = 1000, low = "green", mid = "blue", high = "red")
```