# Colourscale: change where transition starts

Tags: r, colors, heatmap, lattice

I plot heatmaps using the `levelplot` function from the `lattice` package. The values in my matrix range from -1 to 1 and I used the following scale:

```
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(256)
```

A small example:

```
d <- 20
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:d, y = 1:d)
df$z <- runif(d*d, -1, 1)

levelplot(z ~ x * y, data = df,
          col.regions = cols)
```

[image]

I wish to adjust the scale so that a bigger proportion of the scale is white. I assume I have to manually define where the transition starts or better yet define different "transition speeds" - a slower one when I´m closer to 0 (i.e. white), and a quicker one when I get closer to 1 or -1.

Any advice for how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I you're not restricted to use `lattice`, here's how you may do it in `ggplot`: [Is it possible to define the “mid” range in scale_fill_gradient2()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758175/is-it-possible-to-define-the-mid-range-in-scale-fill-gradient2/21758729#21758729)

Comment: Thanks for the link! If possible I would like to stick to lattice because I´d like to plot a pre-existing matrix rather than calculate a correlation matrix and I´ve found this to be easier in lattice...

Comment: OK! But I can assure you, the transistion from `lattice` to `ggplot` is not that difficult. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the interpolation to `spline` for a smoother transition.

```
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"), interpolate = "spline")(256)
```

[image]

You could also go with the much nicer palettes from RColorBrewer

```
cols2 <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))(256)
levelplot(z ~ x * y, data = df, col.regions = rev(cols2))
```

[image]